# Make 100% width div fit within another div and avoid horisontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

So I don't want any horisontal scrollbars but I want the div to fill 100% of it's parent. The code works in FF and IE8 but not for IE7 and below. How can I solve this preferably with CSS only?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto; height:200px;"> 
            <div style="width:100%; height:400px; background:red;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Doctype is set to Transitional

Comment: Next time you ask a question make sure you say exactly what you want so you don't waste anyone's time. "So I don't want any horisontal scrollbars" seemed pretty specific yet you marked as the answer a solution that removed the scrollbars on both axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sounds too simple, but you could set the `height` to `100%`:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background:red;">
```

Comment: The `height` style, as a percentage, takes that percentage of its parent's height. In this case, 200px.

Answer (score 3):

A div will automatically fill the width of it's parent unless specified otherwise.

Strip out the inner width style and the problem will go away.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto; height:200px;"> 
            <div style="height:400px; background:red;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

On a side note. Unless you're building an email you really should be assigning style in an external css file.

Answer (score 0):

The second `div` automatically uses border, which contains `2px` :

`<div style="width:100%; border:none; height:400px; background:red;">`